# menu (file, edit, help ...) that uses jQuery UI css

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

anybody knows a menu plugin that would use jQuery UI css classes, and it would be like windows windows menu (File, Edit, Help)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anything integrates with jquery UI. Your best bet would be to use something like superfish to bring it as close to your needs as possible. Y

http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples